# choose what symbols to export to avoid use of rdynamic option

Tags: gcc

Hello my application is loading a shared library using dlopen. The library needs functions from the application, so I compliled certain sources from the application with the rdynamic option. That means all symbols from that source are exported to the symbol table. My question is: Is it possible to export only certain functions?

Comment: Yes, you can use a linker script listing which symbols to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using gold linker instead of ld. It has `--export-dynamic-symbol` option, which does the exact thing you want.

AFAIC there is no such support for ld.